# How can I create an alias for an edit_path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, authorization

I have an edit_path set up to edit a customer, and it works fine.  However, due to some legacy privilege authorization issues, I need to use a different naming convention for customers, so my privileges are named `action_company` instead of `action_customer`.  I need to be able to use an path like `edit_company_path` but I'm not sure how to get this to work, I  keep getting `undefined method 'edit_company_path'`.  I've tried messing around with the routes, but I'm clearly misunderstanding how Rails maps paths to actions.

How can I map this custom path alias to the correct edit action for customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined method 'edit_company_path'

If you want to *set an alias to an existing edit path*, use `as:`. Something like below

```
#routes.rb

get '/edit/:id', to: 'controller#edit', as: :edit_company
```

This will you the required route helper which you can use.